# Overlay below tiles in Leaflet.js

Tags: javascript, maps, leaflet

I have a Leaflet.js map, with a base tile layer, a label tile layer, and some overlays. I need to put the label tile layer ABOVE the overlays. I tried bringing it to front using `bringToFront()` - for no avail.
Here's the code:

```
map.addLayer( new L.StamenTileLayer("toner-lines") );
...// more code, loading the overlays, etc
var labels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.www.toolserver.org/tiles/osm-labels-en/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17,
    zIndex: 1000
});
labels.addTo(map);
labels.bringToFront();
```

Comment: My guess is that the `bringToFront()` is bringing it to the front of the Tile Layer, which is still below the Overlay layer.  Would you mind creating a jsFiddle replicating the problem so that could be confirmed and a workaround made?

Comment: As per @Josh's advice, here's the JSFiddle:
http://jsfiddle.net/michbarsinai/M29Dk/2/

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The problem is that the entire Tile Layer stack is drawn under the entire Overlay Layer stack and the `bringToFront` and `sendToBack` commands only affect layers within each respective stack.  There is a [bug report](https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/issues/496) detailing this on Leaflet's github site.  It might be fixed in 0.7, but it has already been pushed back a couple of times.

In that bug report, they reference a [workaround by jfirebaugh](http://bl.ocks.org/jfirebaugh/5380413).  That should do what you want.  It adds the, in your case, label layer as a separate DOM layer ontop of the map after everything else has been drawn, using this code:

```
var topPane = map._createPane('leaflet-top-pane', map.getPanes().mapPane);
var topLayer = L.mapbox.tileLayer('lxbarth.map-vtt23b1i').addTo(map);
topPane.appendChild(topLayer.getContainer());
topLayer.setZIndex(9);
```

Comment: Seems not to be fixed in 0.7.3 but in 0.8 dev

Answer (score 3):

For those searching nowaday with Leaflet 1.7.x/1.8.x, you can set the pane for the tilelayer.

Default is the tile pane but you can add this parameter `pane: 'overlayPane'` to add the tilelayer to overlay pane. So the code above would look like this :

```
var labels = L.tileLayer('http://{s}.www.toolserver.org/tiles/osm-labels-en/{z}/{x}/{y}.png', {
    maxZoom: 17,
    zIndex: 1000,
    pane: 'overlayPane'
});
```